# Как вывести значения нечетных элементов массива, их количество и сумму?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int mass1[];
    mass1 = new int[] {3, 5, 9, 10, 11, 14};
    int n=0;
    for(int x=0;x<mass1.length;x++)
    {   
        if(mass1[x]%2-1==0){
            n = mass1[x];
            System.out.println("* Нечетные элементы = " + n);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не знаю Java (например, не знаю, есть ли метод print, но вы можете это сами поправить), но, думаю, в простейшем виде метод может выглядеть следующим образом

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int mass1[] = { 3, 5, 9, 10, 11, 14 };
    int sum = 0;
    int n = 0;

    System.out.println( "Нечетные элементы:" );

    for ( int i = 0; i < mass1.length; i++ )
    {   
        if ( mass1[i] % 2 != 0 )
        {
            ++n
            sum += mass1[i];
            System.out.print( " " + mass1[i] );
        }
    }
    System.out.println( "Всего нечетных элементов " + n );
    System.out.println( "Их сумма равна " + sum );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Поправил, получилось вот такое:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int mass1[];
    mass1 = new int[] {3, 5, 9, 10, 11, 14};
    int sum=0;
    int n=0;

    for(int x=0; x<mass1.length; x++)
    {   
        if( mass1[x]%2-1==0 )
        {
            n++;
            sum += mass1[x];

            System.out.println("Нечетный элемент = " + mass1[x]);
        }
    }

    System.out.println( "Всего нечетных элементов = " + n );
    System.out.println( "Cумма нечетных элементов = " + sum );
}
```